# Buyers remorse... Can I return "Groupons" I bought?

Tags: ecommerce, groupon

I've heard that you are allowed to, but I can't seem to find where to submit the request.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "Yes".

I little bit of google reveals this:

- http://www.groupon.com/legal

  > Can I return a Groupon? Read this, and
  >   then if you want, give us a call:
  >   (877) 788-7858.

And,

- http://groublogpon.com/cities/the-groupon-promise/

> Second, we have The Groupon Promise:
>   if Groupon ever lets you down, we’ll
>   return your purchase—simple as that.